# Codename One simulator became sluggish all of a sudden, and MapContainer shows 404 page

Tags: codenameone

My app features a MapContainer that used to work well in the simulator as well as on the device. However since yesterday (after I sent a build and updated CN1 libs) the simulator has become very sluggish with an app nearly unresponsive (see I can click once on any button or menu and never again since the app does not react any longer). Moreover the MapContainer (GoogleMap ver 19 that was just updated) sometimes shows a 404 page as depicted below :

[image]

Even the Network Monitor gets unresponsive and while starting the app I get the following error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: scale
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2070)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.isRetina(JavaSEPort.java:188)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.<clinit>(JavaSEPort.java:390)
at com.codename1.impl.ImplementationFactory.createImplementation(ImplementationFactory.java:69)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.init(Display.java:467)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1.run(Executor.java:112)
```

Are these 3 issues related to each other, is it linked to the update,a nd what should I do to make my app work again as usual in the simulator ?

*Please note that on the device the generated build works well.*

Any help appreciated,

Comment: That exception should be fixed with today's update (it was just a visual bug). I'm not sure about the other two issues but it's possible that our fix for the retina display on Mac OS caused a regression.

Which OS and JVM are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Shai. I'm looking forward to installing today's update! My dev machine runs 64 bit Linux with java version "1.8.0_112" and I use Netbeans 8.2

Comment: After installing today's update the exception is gone but not the other twi issues. Geolocation also does not work in the simulator. I tried to uninstall / reinstall netbeans with CN1 plugin in vain.

Comment: This might be related to this JVM issue: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8058870 We were able to avoid it until now but it seems we might have hit it. We're looking into it

Comment: Did you achieve to reproduce this issue or do you need more info from me?

Comment: Steve committed a fix for this here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/d401d6f2c9281f43117faadaf6301fc6c7e6fad7

Comment: Great thanks a lot, I'll try it out as soon as the update is avalable!

Comment: Shai, the problem looks mostly solved : the simulator isn't sluggish nor unresponsive anymore. This is great, thanks @SteveHannah! However the 404 page instead of Google's Map still appears when the main form is shown the first time. Indeed if I show another form and go back to the main form then the map appears. Sometimes I get "java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited too long for browser bridge" which had never shown before.

Comment: Great. I'll ask Steve

Comment: I have made a small change that should fix this 404 error also.  [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/15a9d49ea73148a73ff5bd5a983b56483c5e9e89) . It will be available in next update

Comment: Great thanks Steve!